# How do I stop getting charged for an app I deleted?

Tags: applications

I downloaded Recolor app. Hen I got a bill and did not know there was a charge for this app. I deleted the app and on the receipt I received I reported the problem that I didn't know there was a charge. I thought that this would stop me from getting charged. But I am still getting charges

Can you help me?

Answer (score 6):

There is such a thing as app subscriptions which will just be billed to the card associated with the app store.

Go to the app store, scroll to the bottom click your username, click view account, then hit Manage, then find the app that has a subscription added to it, click it and then hit the automatic renewal toggle to off.

You had purchased the app subscription which is why it's billing you

[image: you bought the Recolor unlimited subscription]

Answer (score 1):

On the App Store, if you bought the app and it asked you for a password for payment of currency, even if you deleted the app, Apple will not give you a refund, as far as I know.

In Apple's [Media Services Terms and Conditions](https://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/itunes/us/terms.html), § B, “Payments, Taxes, and Refunds,” it is stated,

> Apple will charge your payment method (such as your credit card, debit card, gift card/code, or other method [sic] available in your Home Country) for any paid Transactions, including any applicable taxes. If you pre-order Content, you will be charged when the Content is delivered to you (unless you cancel prior to the Content’s availability). For details about how Transactions are billed, please visit http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5582. All Transactions are final.